# Select from database in groups

Tags: php, mysql

Im just getting back into programming, haven't for a long time... but no there is something wired and i don't know if i'm just really rusty and have something wrong or just don't get it ^^

I have a table in my DB

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3
1  | aaaaaaa | 1111111 | zzzzzzz
2  | bbbbbbb | 2222222 | zzzzzzz
3  | ccccccc | 3333333 | zzzzzzz
4  | ddddddd | 4444444 | yyyyyyy
5  | eeeeeee | 5555555 | yyyyyyy
6  | fffffff | 6666666 | xxxxxxx
7  | ggggggg | 77777777| zzzzzzz
```

Now I want to select the whole content grouped by `column3` *(Actually I don't know its content)*.

The result I want to achieve is:

**first group**

```
1  | aaaaaaa | 1111111 | zzzzzzz
2  | bbbbbbb | 2222222 | zzzzzzz
3  | ccccccc | 3333333 | zzzzzzz
```

**second group**

```
4  | ddddddd | 4444444 | yyyyyyy
5  | eeeeeee | 5555555 | yyyyyyy
```

**third group**

```
6  | fffffff | 6666666 | xxxxxxx
```

**is this possible with a select ?** or do I have to select all and fill it into an array setting the key like

```
foreach($result as $res)
    $data[$res['column3']][] = $res;
```

I don't know why but my thoughts were that:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY column3
```

would do the trick but I'm obviously wrong :)

### EDIT: Solution

> Actually column3 is a timestamp that gets update on edit. It only will be updated once so this
>   timestamp only changes once. I have to select it by Day so I use it like this...

```
$result = $this->pdo->query("SELECT dbx_id, ordernumber, debited, timestamp FROM " . TABLE_HISTORY . " WHERE dbx_id=:dbx_id AND debited=1", array(":dbx_id" => $dbx_id), true);

foreach($result as $part){
    $data[date('d-m-Y', strtotime($part['timestamp']))][] = $part;
}
```

***Thanks to all who tried to help***

Comment: A single SELECT cannot return three results.

Comment: Group by is not a where !? You have to do 3 requests.

`where column3 = 'zzzzzzz'`
`where column3 = 'yyyyyyy'`
`where column3 = 'xxxxxxx'`

Comment: @JayBlanchard and when I use sub-selects ?

Comment: A SELECT with subs still returns one result.

Comment: so I won't come around my php array build ....

Comment: You can do it with 2 sql, first `SELECT distinct(column3) FROM myTable` second `SELECT * FROM myTable where column3 = "$row['colum3']"`

edit : your code can work, just remove GROUP By

Comment: I understand what your goal is with this. but I dont understand why. what good is returning the data like this? and are you saying you just want each "group" of column3 to be stored in a separate array in php? how are you trying to manipulate what is returned from the database?

Comment: however you can try to use a union distinct in your case

Comment: @MarcoMura a union would only return the data how the table is already laid out.. am I wrong?

Comment: @JohnRuddell you are wrong lol, you can do an union from two different select as example, if they have the same source table you can put different logic. We use it on Oracle. Well, you cannot order the table with union but you can put a not existent field to help "sort" this.

Comment: @MarcoMura no I understand how a union works.. thats not what I was saying... look at the table. and then look at each of the groups he wants to return... a UNION would only put more rows below the first select.. but since the groups are already in that order (or could easily be ordered by that) i don't see the use in the UNION overhead of 3 selects

Comment: `UNION` still returns one resultset.

Comment: **Any** query you run will return a single resultset...

Comment: @JohnRuddell i've re-read the question. Doesn't he simple need sorting instead of group?

Comment: @MIvanIsten exactly, which is why I don't get what good a UNION would do

Comment: @MarcoMura: he doesn't need sorting.

Comment: @MarcoMura I don't think so but i;m not sure... read the first comment i put up... what is the OP trying to do with the data.. does he want separate arrays?

Comment: @JohnRuddell as long as the owner doesn't really explain what he need we can only try.

Comment: First of all I want to thank all for this good going conversation :) In the end is kind of a sorting i need. In my case column3 is a field (timespamp) and gets set on update. Actually its when a user does a dataexport. So it can be that he exports 3 times in one day but I still want to select this as one. (Exporthistory per day). Now i tried to achieve this with a select and return this all as a Array using PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your `foreach` idea. `GROUP BY` is for use with aggregate functions like `COUNT`, `SUM`, etc [See manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

I like your `foreach` idea,  and I don't see a way around it since you can't get multiple results from one query. Your best bet is to parse out the groups in code. You don't even need the `GROUP BY` clause. I would specify an `ORDER BY` but even that is not necessary.

Psuedocode:

`SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column3;`

```
$aryGroups = array();
foreach($result as $row){
  if( ! isset($aryGroups[$row['column3']]) ){
    $aryGroups[$row['column3']] = array();
  }
  else{
    $aryGroups[$row['column3']][] = $row;
  }
}
```

I've used something like this a few times, but you may need to tweak it to get the exact results you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a union? You could identify the groups within each join for example:

```
SELECT "Group1" AS whichGroup, * FROM myTable WHERE column3 LIKE "zzzzzzz"
UNION ALL
SELECT "Group2" AS whichGroup, * FROM myTable WHERE column3 LIKE "yyyyyyy"
UNION ALL
SELECT "Group3" AS whichGroup, * FROM myTable WHERE column3 LIKE "xxxxxxx"
```

Not 100% on that syntax as it's been a while since I used a union, but this would group them for your output, and allows you to do it all within MySQL, although I think it's just as easy to do the heavy lifting in PHP instead...

If I'm right, this should output something like:

```
whichGroup | id | column1 | column2 | column3
Group1     | 1  | aaaaaaa | 1111111 | zzzzzzz
Group1     | 2  | bbbbbbb | 2222222 | zzzzzzz
Group1     | 3  | ccccccc | 3333333 | zzzzzzz
Group2     | 4  | ddddddd | 4444444 | yyyyyyy
Group2     | 5  | eeeeeee | 5555555 | yyyyyyy
Group3     | 6  | fffffff | 6666666 | xxxxxxx
```

Comment: I should point out that while this does group them and pull the data in one MySQL query, I don't believe it really accomplishes anything that isn't already accomplished by using column3 name itself.

Comment: actually it's a huge table and i don't know the content of column 3. The only thing I know about it is that some of the become the same entry if there is made a special update. May I also have to only take a part of that String to compare (group).